# jstl creating and closing div inside if condition in a loop xhtml

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, foreach, xhtml, jstl

I am creating div elements dynamically in my xhtml file, using a forEach loop. Every 3 iterations I need to create a div with class="row" to be the parent of 3 elements and I need to close it after 3 more iterations are complete. The following is my code:

```
<c:set var="count" value="1" scope="view" />
        <c:forEach items="#{BiletaBean.dsCat}" var="dsC">
            <c:if test="${count == 1}">
                <div class="row">
            </c:if>
            <div class="panel panel-primary col-lg-3" style="padding:0">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white;">
                    SOT ${dsC.BA} ${dsC.category}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="background: #337ab7; color: white;"> 
                    <div style="color: white;" class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 clearfix">Te gjeneruara:</div><div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="font-size:26px" >#{dsC.generated}</div>
                    <div style="color: white; clear:left" class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 clearfix">Te validuara:</div><div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="font-size:26px" >#{dsC.validated}</div>
                    <div style="color: white; clear:left" class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 clearfix">Totali Leke:</div><div id="amount" class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="font-size:26px" >#{dsC.totalMoney}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <c:if test="${count == 3}">
                </div>
            </c:if>
            <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="view"/>
            <c:if test="${count > 3}">
                <c:set var="count" value="1" scope="view"/>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:if test="${count != 1}">
            </div>
        </c:if>
```

However, I am getting the following error when trying to open the page in a browser:

> Error Parsing /dashboard.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 55] The element
>   type "div" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

I guess it is referring to the opening  and it's saying that it cannot find a closing div for that one, even though I'm quite certain that every div that is opened, is also closed.

Can anyone help by telling me why am I getting that error? Can I solve it somehow? If not, can someone suggest another way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: That's right, XML doesn't work like that. Rewrite it, by using (pseudo code) `<if test> <div>content</div> </if> <if not test> content only </if>`

Comment: By the way, you have `count==1` in the condition for the start tag and `count==3` for the end tag. This is not causing the xml error, but it's something you might look into.

Comment: @mr-lister
You're right about what you're saying at the first comment, however that is not what I want to achieve. I need to create the opening <div class="row"> when it is the first of 3 iterations and create the closing one at the last of the 3 iterations. Therefore, I cannot include the opening div, the content and the closing div in the same if statement because I'm not achieving what I want by doing so. Here is the same thing achieved through PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766409/using-php-loop-to-add-bootstrap-rows-and-proper-column-numbers-to-elements

Comment: Yes, you can do that with PHP. But PHP is not written in XML. You are trying to do things with XML that simply cannot be done in XML. Rethink your strategy.