# Dynamically create a grid layout using div tag in PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

So I have a question similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766409/using-php-loop-to-add-bootstrap-rows-and-proper-column-numbers-to-elements) but I'm applying it only in vanilla PHP and not in wordpress. After countless hours of struggle I finally got the answer but somehow if I increase the size of my grid number the items are not aligning.

**I want it to look like this:**

```
-----------
- 1 2 3 4 -
-----------
```

**But:**
As stated on my problem if I tried to increase the grid (or more precisely the item) it becomes like this:

```
-----------
- 1 2 3 4 -
-   5     -
-6        -
-7        -
-----------
```

It becomes cluttered. Below is the code that I'm trying to experiment.

```
<div class="container">
<?php
$i=0;
$item=0;
$html_tag = '<div class = "row"><div class="col 3">';

while($item <= 4)
{
?>
    <?php if($i % 4 == 0) {
        $html_tag .= 'col '.$i.'</div>';
    }
    else {
        $html_tag .= '<div class="col"> col '.$i.'</div>';
    }
    ?>
<?php
    $i++;
    $item++;
}
$html_tag .= '</div>';
?>

<?php echo $html_tag ?>
```

P.S. I'm using twitter bootstrap 4 for it's responsiveness.

EDIT:

Notice the screenshot below, I just realized that there is an extra text which is 'col ?3' inside the div row instead of another div column (which wasn't created).

[image]

Comment: Have you use the inspect feature on the browser to see the actual code that gets rendered?

Comment: i did... but I'm having trouble organizing the actual code., i can't seem to control as to where or how i place the if statement

Comment: you can use css display grid property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inspect your code, the final structure is not correct.

This is what you got

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col 3">col 0</div>
        <div class="col"> col 1</div>
        <div class="col"> col 2</div>
        <div class="col"> col 3</div>
        col 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Try with this code

```
$html = '';
$totalItemPerLine = 3;
$totalItem = 7;
for($i = 0; $i < $totalItem; $i++)
{
    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == 0)
    {
        $html .= '<div class="row">'; // OPEN ROW
    }

    $html .= '<div class="col"> col '.$i.'</div>';

    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == ($totalItemPerLine-1))
    {
        $html .= '</div>'; // CLOSE ROW
    }
}

echo $html;
```

**NOTE:** You could do exactly the same with a `while`, but I used a `for` for the readability

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment @DavidDiaz this is the code directly with HTML
But I recommend you to learn POO and use class to do this page

```
$html = '';
$totalItemPerLine = 3;
$totalItem = 7;
for($i = 0; $i < $totalItem; $i++)
{
    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == 0)
    {?>
        <div class="row"> <!-- OPEN ROW -->
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="col"> col <?= $i ?> </div>

    <?php if($i % $totalItemPerLine == ($totalItemPerLine-1))
    { ?>
        </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: thanks, did the trick.,, Iill dig into your code more so I could have a good grasp of it.,

Comment: If you have more questions, I'm here. Don't forget to accept my answer please ;)

Comment: by the way., if I were to code it into like '<?php if($i % $totalItemPerLine == 0)
    {?> <div class = "row"> <?php } ?>', will it still work? As you can see it's suppose to have lots of div elements but due too how complicated I tried to solve it I decided it to experiment on it with minimal elements.

Comment: here is the [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yym4px1piar4dl/probz.jpg?dl=0) of what I wanted to actually put.

Comment: If you want to print directly some HTML, you can but you have to do it everywhere and delete the variable `$html`. 
In you screenshort there is only one column, is that what you want ? So why try to do a real grid ?

Comment: while I already know for a fact that I have to delete the variable as for the column the reason I only have one is that it's supposed to be dynamic. I mean the questions that I've posted were all part of that single column that needs to be turn into grid. That was just plain html since I deleted the php code due to how I find it difficult in placing the right if/else statement.

Comment: Ok, so check my post, I just edit my answer with an example in plain HTML.
But as I recommend you in the post, try to learn POO and do a class and function for this page, it will be so much clearer ;)

Comment: if you want here is the actual [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/04ak55tqfp0qilh/code.php?dl=0) some parts were omitted for brevity. cheers.

Comment: thanks dude by the way can you enlighten on what's POO? i thought you meant to say OOP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174174/discussion-between-d-schreier-and-david-diaz).

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with the accepted answer. It doesn't close the last row. It needs another condition.

```
$html = '';
$totalItemPerLine = 3;
$totalItem = 7;
for($i = 0; $i < $totalItem; $i++)
{
    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == 0)
    {
        $html .= '<div class="row">'; // OPEN ROW
    }

    $html .= '<div class="col"> col '.$i.'</div>';

    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == ($totalItemPerLine-1) || $i == ($totalItems-1))
    {
        $html .= '</div>'; // CLOSE ROW
    }
}

echo $html;
```