# How do I display first four records with col-12 and reset records will display in something like col-8(col-6 and col-6)

Tags: html, wordpress, post, bootstrap-4

I am displaying recent posts on my home page which are displaying on my WordPress website. Now I have to display records in the bootstrap column like the below image.

[image]

Explanation of the image:

1) The first four rows will display col 12.

2) Then I have to divide columns 8 and 4.

3) In column 8 I have to display the reset of my records in col 6-6.

4) In column 4 I have to display some static text which is not coming from the database.

So my HTML code will display like this.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                        <!-- and so on -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <!-- html text this is not apart of for each-->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

My expected output is

[image]

I am confused about how to do this. Currently, I am getting all the records in col 12. Below is my code.

```
function recentPost_on_home2(){
ob_start();
?>
<div class="cp-seeWrapper">
    <div class="row">
   <?php 
    global $paged;
    $paged = $paged ? $paged : get_query_var( 'page' );
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 6,'paged'=> $paged,);
    $tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {

               while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $tyler_query->the_post();
                    $names = array();
                    $categories = get_the_category();
                    foreach ( $categories as $i => $term ) {
                        if ( $i < 1 ) { // show at most two
                            $names[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $term->term_id ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                    $names = implode( '', $names );
                    ?>
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="cp-shadow cp-seeSinglePostWrapper">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute('echo=0'));?>" class=""><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
                        <div class="bg-white single-post-box">
                            <div class="d-flex cp-CategoryList">
                                <div class="seeDate"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y');?></div>
                                <div class="cp_cat_list"><?php echo $names;?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cp-b-content">
                                <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute('echo=0'));?>" class=""><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 12, '...');?></a>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 25, '...');?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php  }?>

    <?php   }?>

    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="cp-social cp-shadow bg-white">
                <h3>Social</h3>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cp-postPagination">
         <div class="nav-previous cp-pagi float-left"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
         <div class="nav-next cp-pagi float-right"><?php next_posts_link( null, $tyler_query->max_num_pages ); ?> </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    <?php return ob_get_clean(); 
}
add_shortcode( 'home_recent_post2', 'recentPost_on_home2' );
```

Comment: Note: col-12 is just an example for col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my solution. I don't know it's a correct way or not but it's solved my issue.

**I am just sharing the sample of the code**

What I did, 
I added `container` and `row` both class out of the loop and declare two php variable called as `$index = 0; $check=0;` before while loop.

Then I added `if-else` condition inside while loop and condition is `if ($index < 4)`. Why 4 because I have to display the first 4 rows with col 12. So I am getting the first 4 rows with 12 columns.

Then in the `else` condition, I added

```
if ($check==0){?>
<div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="row">
<?php $check=1;}?>
```

why above code because the above code will work only once in a while loop so it's created by 8 columns.
After else close, I added `$index++;` for increment the records.

that's it. I got my expected output.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {
      $index = 0; 
      $check=0;
      while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) {
      if ($index < 4) {?>
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <?php  } else {              
           if ($check==0){?>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <?php $check=1;}?>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <!--content-->
        </div>
        <?php   } $index++;}?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <!-- html text this is not apart of for each-->
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate :

**EDIT**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  …
  …
  …
  $index = 0;
  foreach ( $categories as $i => $term ) {
    if ($index < 3) {
      <div class="col-12">…</div>
    } else {
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">…</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">…</div>
      <div class="col-auto">…</div>
    }
    $index++;
  }
  …
  </div>
</div>
```

I put to logic, your work to put the php / html syntax ! Good luck :)

**Don't forget that :**

- `col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` is the exact same thing as `col-12`(check this [Bootstrap grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options))
- It is as really bad practice to put `row` then `col` then `row` again etc… just put **ONE** `row` then put your `col` then close your `row`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying to achieve using foreach or while loop because  I am getting the data from the database.

Comment: Wait I think you applied the if the condition in the wrong place. if ($i < 3) {  is displaying my categories name which I called in side column. I think I have to apply your logic here while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) {

Comment: Your above logic is not working. I mean if ($i < 3) (I have 10 posts)then it will always display the else part.

Comment: @NarenVerma i edited it again, created a index variable that will increment

Comment: I tried your code if the condition is working. I am getting the first 3 records col-12 but remaining records are not working as I expected else part is not working. Else part records are displaying     <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">…</div> I need <class="col-8><div class="col-6"></div><div class="col-6"></div><!--and so on--></div>